# XMLSlurper Groovy -

Tags: html, groovy, xmlslurper

Is it possible with XLMSlurper to output all the text below a node without losing the tags?

```html
<DIV1> 
  <p>text text text <b>strong</b></p> 
  <img ...></img> 
</DIV1>
```

I want to practically extract the text inside the DIV1 tag without losing the HTML tags.
The XML is not formatted with CDATA, so this solution is not possible for me.

Would be nice if someone have a solution for me...

Comment: What have you tried ? Add your code and the errors you are getting to your question so that we can help you.

Comment: Thank you! I have solved my problem. I first mark all relevant nodes with my individual tags and then I replaced them with the special html code.